# Wordpress admin panel functions does not work

Tags: wordpress, admin

After updating wordpress to 3.9 some of the functions stop working in the admin panel. When i editing a page upload featured imege button, and upload media button just dont work (it just bring me to the top of the page). I cant open or close the "editing sections" whit the little arrows, and cant open the "what we see" panel at the top of the page.

Thanx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these steps will help:

- **Clear browser cache** (after a major WP update this is kinda nessessary)
- **Disable all your plugins** and activate them one by one and check if this problem still occur
- **Update your plugins**